# django: filtering with multiple criteria without losing other fields?

Tags: sql, django

My model looks like so: Each `Bottle` has an attribute `name`, and a relationship to `Brand`.

In one of my views, I want to show a user all distinct bottles, and their counts.

A distinct bottle is a bottle that has the same `name` attribute, and the same `Brand` relationship.

So this table:[image]

Should display 2 lines instead of 3, with the proper quantities (1 for Eitan, 2 for Almon).

The following line in my `views.py`:

```
object = Bottle.objects.filter(brand__business__owner_id=user.id).all().values('name').annotate(Count('brand'))
```

Produces this when I print `object`:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'Almon', 'brand__count': 2}, {'name': 'Eitan', 'brand__count': 1}]>
```

Which *seems* to be the right direction, but it has two problems:

1. I lose all other fields (`vintage`, `capacity`) except `name` and `brand__count`. I can of course explicitly add them to values, but that seems a) upythonic b) that it will group_by these items as well!
2. My pug template complains: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1 (this is because I'm iterating through them as a list, and using its index for numbering)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object = Bottle.objects.filter(brand__business__owner_id=user.id).all().values('name','vintage','capacity').annotate(Count('brand'))
```

unless you mention the fields to filter as you are mentioning name then how will the query set pass it to you? then do this, like not mentioning any name in the values

```
object = Bottle.objects.filter(brand__business__owner_id=user.id).all().values().annotate(Count('brand'))
```

both of this will give you all the fields in Bottle table

Comment: So where is this grouping by the Bottle's name and its brand?

Comment: check the both you will understand. give it a try first

Comment: OK they both output all fields except the `brand__name` which is the bottle's brand name. So as I understand and before I check your answer as the correct one: I have to explicitly call the fields when I want a related-entity attribute?

Comment: yes, because without that django wont understand which fields you want to get, and particularly for those which has foreign feilds

Comment: Appreciate your help!

Comment: no worry mate. ask anything if you face any other problem, will gladly help